# Deserialize json with array of different types using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datacontractjsonserializer

Is there a way to deserialize such json

```
{
  "photos": [
    19,
    {
      "pid": 288777129,
      "aid": -6
    },
    {
      "pid": 286441792,
      "aid": -6
    },
    {
      "pid": 114893258,
      "aid": 34465839
    }
  ]
}
```

with C# `DataContractJsonSerializer` without modifying the source. I mean the first element 19.

Comment: JSON Arrays are not restricted to one type (So the json is valid), in fact in javascript those objects would be all considered as different types in a sense because they are just generic object literals.

Comment: I've edited the question title to be more correct.

Comment: Did you find an answer? Or you ended up not using DataContract

Comment: @FYaqoob, i gave up using DataContractJsonSerializer and switched to custom converter solution  with Json.NET

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the `JavascriptSerializer` class instead:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Object obj = js.DeserializeObject(str);
Response.Write(obj["photos"][0]); // 19
```

Comment: Unfortunately i need DataContract support while deserializing.